# Streaming MacBook to TV

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook and recently tried connecting it to my TV with a HDMI cord. I bought the adapter so I am all set there.

My issue was when I plugged it into the TV it only showed my background. I Googled and saw someone suggest dragging the screen all the way to the left which I did and it worked but it took the screen off my computer so it wasn't visible there any longer.

My other issue was the TV picture kept freezing. The sound was good but the picture was not. Any suggestions? Trying not to buy Apple TV at this point but will if I have to.

Answer (score 3):

Open System Preferences, click Displays, click arrangement, click mirror checkbox in bottom left corner of window.